# Fetch data on ASP.NET Core with Angular template stuck on loading. VS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, templates, fetch-api

this is my first post here so sorry if I forget about some data. My issue is that I run ASP.NET Core with Angular template in Visual Studio 2019 and when I open the project in the browser, on localhost:4200 as it is as default, the Fetch data tab stuck on loading since the very beginning. It looks like the app doesn't fetch data at all. I'm quite new to Angular this is also my first step.

fetch-data.component.html code:

```
<h1 id="tableLabel">Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!forecasts"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel" *ngIf="forecasts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Temp. (C)</th>
      <th>Temp. (F)</th>
      <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
      <td>{{ forecast.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

fetch-data.component.ts code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'weatherforecast').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
  date: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}
```

The issue occurs even when I haven't changed anything so I presume it's some settings that I haven't done. I've tried tips from here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85 with creation proxy.conf.json file, but it didn't work.Can anyone give me a tip? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best practice to call the API is in `ngOnInit`. So put the api calling code in that and verify if its working. Also verify the url is formed correctly.

Comment: First thing I would try is to disable your firewall TEMPORARY only to see if this is the cause. If that fixes it then you'll need to add some exceptions

Comment: @DaveWuzHere unfortunately it didn't work. Nothing has changed after disable my firewall.